# telnet protocol: response to break

Tags: tcp, telnet

I've got a C++ server application which provides a listening TCP port for support personnel to connect to. They can issue commands and get responses. It's working fine from the application perspective.

My problem arises when they use *telnet(1)* to connect, and if they (for some reason) type a ^C. My server sees the parsed control characters that *telnet* sends me, and I can ignore or process them as I see fit. But the *telnet* client itself goes into some state where it stops outputting my server's responses to the client's screen.

I know I could either 1) tell them not to use *telnet* or 2) tell them to do a `toggle autoflush` inside the telnet app, or via `~/.telnetrc` or whatever. But what I would *prefer* to do, if possible, is respond in the server with the correct protocol sequence to get their client to do the right thing with the text that follows. This just feels like it'd be a better UX for them. Their job sucks enough as it is.

Is this possible? I've been through the RFC and it's not clear. From my own past use of *telnet* in the past, this feels like it's doable, but my memory may be fuzzy.

Comment: You need to invesigate why the client is behaving like that, if you can. The only action required when you receive a break is to stop what you're doing. There is no protocol response.

Comment: This is the standard linux telnet client.

Comment: i would try few more TELNET clients, just to check if they all behaves the same way.

Comment: You could try sending DATA MARK and the associated urgent data. What actual message did you receive on the Ctrl/c?

Comment: The ^C sends FF F4 FF FD 06, which is IAC IP and  IAC DO TIMING-MARK.  Responding with DM and friends doesn't seem to change the client state.

Comment: Are you sending IAC WILL or WONT TIMING-MARK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind `IAC DO TIMING-MARK` (`FF FD 06`) is to suppress the output of the process that is to be interrupted by the `IAC IP` interrupt process (`FF F4`) command. In this way the telnet client program hides all output from the user until it receives a proper timing mark or notification that timing mark is not supported by the server.

You may or may not respond or take action to the `IAC IP` but you have to respond to `IAC DO TIMING-MARK`. The easiest way in your case is to respond that you ignored it by `IAC WONT TIMING-MARK` (`FF FC 06`) and the client should continue displaying all the output normally.

If you really terminate the current job, then you should flush your buffers and then respond with `IAC WILL TIMING-MARK`, which means that the client will discard all server's output from the moment the user pushed `^C` to the place in the stream where it finds the `IAC WILL TIMING-MARK` (`FF FB 06`).